# What if the initial data curve coincides with a characteristic?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristic-functions, characteristics

I am trying to solve this problem:
$u_x+2xu_y$=y, with u(0,y) = 1+$y^2$ for $\frac{-1}{2} < y < \frac{1}{2}$ and determine the greatest region in which a unique solution exists.

I have found the solution to this problem as well as its characteristics s = x and t = y-$x^2$, but I have not idea on how to find the region in which the solution is unique. I know that I should find a region in which the characteristics intersect the initial data curve exactly once, but here the initial data curve i.e. y-axis happens to be one of the characteristics i.e. x = 0. If I remove this characteristic, then the initial data curve will also be removed, and (I think) the solution will not exist at all, let alone being unique.

Can anyone help me on this question? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The two characteristics are $$x^{2} - y = C_{1}, \quad u - \left(- \frac{2x^{3}}{3} + x y \right) = C_{2}$$

Comment: The initial data curve doesn't coincide with a characteristic. OK with  Matthew Cassell.

Comment: hi, thank you for your help! Can you explain more on how the second characteristic is obtained? The aproach I was taught to find characteristics is different from yours. Thank you! @MatthewCassell

Comment: The characteristic curves come from solving two of the following three equalities
$$\frac{dx}{1} = \frac{dy}{2x} = \frac{du}{y}$$
You already have the first characteristic from solving across the first equality above. Substitute this result into the $du$ ratio
$$\frac{dx}{1} = \frac{du}{y} = \frac{du}{x^{2} - C_{1}}$$ 
and then solve
\begin{align}
du &= (x^{2} - C_{1}) dx \\
\implies u - \left(\frac{x^{3}}{3} - C_{1} x \right) &= u - \left(- \frac{2x^{3}}{3} + x y \right) \\
&= C_{2}
\end{align}
To finish, note that $C_{2} = f(C_{1})$ for an arbitrary differentiable function $f$.

Comment: The general solution is: $$u\! \left(x,y\right)=-\frac{2 x^{3}}{3}+x y+f_{1}\! \left(-x^{2}+y\right)$$
We then choose $f_1(z)=1+z^2$ to satisfy the boundary condition $u(0,y)=1+y^2$:

$$u(x,y)=-\frac{2\cdot x^{3}}{3}+y\cdot x+\left(-x^{2}+y\right)^{2}+1$$